# Signal processing

Tags: signal-analysis, python

I am quite new to signal processing and I have got the signal in picture. I'm working with Python.

[image]

The central part has some sort of periodicity and it is the one I want to retain, whereas I want to remove the part of the signal close to zero or the strange peaks at the beginning and at the end. How can I do this in an automatic way? I need to perform this task for many similar signals.

Comment: Can you please post a figure in which you have marked exactly which parts you would like to retain and which parts you would like to reject from this waveform?

Comment: i have updated the question. The part I want to maitain is the one inside the red box.

Comment: Thank you, there seem to be two traces depicted in this figure. What is the second trace? (very low amplitude sort of dark olive colour)

Comment: The light green signal contains the labels for a classification task based on the darker signal, however it cannot be used to perform the cropping I am asking for, so please just ignore it.